# How to insert a revision number in string

Tags: batch-file

I’m using the following script to add a revision number to a .stp file. For example: ABS0012033.stp to ABS0012033_rev001.stp. This is working well.
Now I have some files that end with _asm.stp, for example, ABS0012033_asm.stp. How do I need to modify the script that it works for both file types?

Some additional information: There is only one .stp file to be renamed per time and then the .stp file will be moved to another folder. The text file which contains the revision number is temporary and will be deleted after renaming the .stp file.
The current script does remove the last 4 characters from the filename and stores the filename in variable str1. Then it renames the filename with str1 + revision number.

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=2" %%a IN (`findstr REVISION C:\PUBLISH_WORKSPACE\*.txt`) do (
  SET Rev=%%a)
FOR %%S IN ( c:\publish_workspace\*.STP) DO (SET FILE=%%S)
set str1=%file:~21,-4%
ren %file% %str1%_rev%REV%.stp
EXIT
```

I have tried to implement an IF function in the following script, but it doesn’t work. It doesn’t write str1 when renaming the filename. Any ideas what the problem could be?

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=2" %%a IN (`findstr REVISION C:\PUBLISH_WORKSPACE\*.txt`) do (
  SET Rev=%%a)
FOR %%S IN ( c:\publish_workspace\*.STP) DO (SET FILE=%%S)
echo.%FILE%|findstr /C:"_asm" >nul 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 (
   set str1=%file:~21,-8%
ren %file% %str1%_rev%REV%.stp
) else (
   set str1=%file:~21,-4%
ren %file% %str1%_rex%REV%.stp
)
pause
move c:\publish_workspace\*.stp c:\publish_workspace\stp
del c:\publish_workspace\*.txt
EXIT
```

Comment: Are you expecting ABS0012033_asm.stp to result in ABS0012033_asm_rev001.stp or ABS0012033_rev001_asm.stp?

Comment: ABS0012033_rev001, (remove _asm)

Comment: If you have two files `ABS0012033_asm.stp` and `ABS0012033.stp`, they cannot both be renamed to `ABS0012033_rev001.stp`! Also what happens to any file which already has the `_rev001` basename suffix? Your script would have to ignore them all otherwise it would not know the difference between `_rev001.stp` and `_asm.stp`. In addition, what happens if there's already a `ABS0012033_rev001.stp`, is the script supposed to determine that, and create one named `ABS0012033_rev002.stp` instead?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.
There is only one file to be renamed per time and then the file will be moved to another folder (I have removed this line from the script). The file name is either ABS0012033.stp OR ABS0012033_asm.stp which must be changed to ABS0012033_rev001.stp. The rev number is taken from a separate temporary text file and stored as variable REV

Comment: So there is only ever going to be one STP file, but you will not know its name. Are we to assume that there is always only ever going to be one file with an extension beginning with `.txt` too, and you also will not know its name either? And could you please provide its content, formatted as code, by way of an [edit] to your question.

Comment: I have already updated the initial question. I hope it is clear now, otherwise let me know

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not sure to understand the problem. What about this?

```
set Rev=ren001
ren ABS???????_asm.stp ABS???????_%Rev%.stp
```

Comment: it is not an answer. You can create another question if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This answer makes assumptions, those assumptions could have been resolved had you responded to my comment one day ago.

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
PushD "C:\Publish_Workspace" 2>NUL && (Set "Rev=") || GoTo :EOF
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "REVISION" "*.txt"') Do Set "Rev=%%H"
If Not Defined Rev GoTo :EOF
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Set "PathExt=" ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe ".":"*.stp" 2^>NUL') Do For /F Delims^=_^ EOL^= %%H In ("%%~nG") Do Ren "%%G" "%%H_rev%Rev:* =%%%~xG"
```

*I am not a tutor, and will not be providing additional explanation, other than to refer you to my comments, and the built-in help information for each command, (`commandName /?`).*